# Passing variables from javasctipt to php whit $.ajax method, for posting in database mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I try to make POST call from js file to php. I need this to add variable in mySQL database.

There are my simple files:

1° PHP file, used for send call

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/ajax-call.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

file js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/json/html/j.php',

        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            "variable":"foo"
        },

        success: function () {
            console.log("ok");

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

php code of recever:

```
<?php
    function connect(){
        $connect = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','') or die("ERROR");
        $connect2Database = mysql_select_db('ajax', $connect);
        return $connect;
    }

    if(isset($_POST)){
        if($connect = connect()){
            $query = "INSERT INTO `table`(`name`) VALUES ('".$_POST['variable']."');";
            $completeQuery = mysql_query($query, $connect);
        }
    }
?>
```

The variable $_POST['variable'] is undefined. I try to sobstitute $_POST['variable'] with an easy string and it was added to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `contentType` to `'application/json'`, raw JSON string is sent to the server. Instead, you should remove that part and do a regular `POST`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/json/html/j.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        "variable":"foo"
    },

    success: function () {
        console.log("ok");

    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```